# Remove hovercard for only certian gravatars

Tags: plugins, avatar, gravatar

I am using the [Extended Gravatar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-gravatar/) plugin by Reza Moallemi and it works great. However, on my about page I have a large gravatar to show the author. I would like to know if there is a class I can add to not show the hovercard. Or php that can be added to [get_avatar('$email')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)

I could just not include the plugin on the about page but I'm thinking there is an easier way to fix this.

Comment: Any progress, or is this an abandoned question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @toscho has seemed to have revived this question here is one way to do it (not saying it's the best but it works) It's important to note I've switched to [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) which has hovercards built in. If you are using Jetpack here's how you do it.

```
function nifty_remove_grofiles() {
  if(is_page('about')){
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'grofiles_attach_cards' );
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'nifty_remove_grofiles');
```

this basically tells the JavaScript that controls the hovercards not to load on the `about` page.